# mvc 3 windows authentification doesn`t work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I have my intranet app with windows authentication.

On my local machine I run this app perfectly. I enters localhost/blabla and I get immediately on Index page.

I deployed my app on a server (IIS 7) in the same domain. And when I try to get Index from any intranet machine(except server of course) I get a login/pass form, where I must input my domain login and pass.

The question is - how to make browser not to ask already known data such as login and pass?

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: Depends which browser you're using. AFAIK this is only possible in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on browser, IE will work out of the box.

FF look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080531061006/http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/) and Chrome look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/10801/windows-authentication-with-google-chrome).

Comment: So i cant force it from my app? Like when i force css hack for IE?))

Comment: Not as far as I am aware ... no

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using different authentication settings for the app pool in IIS than on your local implementation.
If not, also remember that when you run the app on your local machine, IIS will in some cases use your own credentials to access the domain, whereas you would have to supply the app with a login when it runs on IIS somewhere else. You can do this in your web.config by specifying:

```
<identity impersonate="true"
      userName="domain\user" 
      password="password" />
```

Comment: So, when I add my login\pass to my app, it means that only this login and pass will not be asked when I enter site? Or it is just credentials to login to IIS?